# Tile Images are not Showing when i put app in store for windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I used this below code to pin the tile, and here i used TileNotificationsPack.dll for updating tile.

```
Uri Squarelogo = new Uri(ms-appx:///TileImages/150x150.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Uri Widelogo = new Uri(ms-appx:///TileImages/310x150.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Uri smalllogo = new Uri(ms-appx::///TileImages/30x30.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(ShowId, title, ProjectName, tileActivationArguments, TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo, Widelogo);
secondaryTile.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Light;              
secondaryTile.WideLogo = Widelogo;
secondaryTile.Logo = Squarelogo;
secondaryTile.SmallLogo = smalllogo;
await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Tile image showing in debug mode only when i put app in store tile images are not showing..

Comment: Which image is not showing? I tested with your code after added quotation marks in `Uri`, you code works well and I can see the images I've set.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT yes..that code is working for me in debug mode..but when i put that app in  store tile image not showing..

Comment: You are using images in app's `LocalFolder`. Are you sure you have these images in it? When you first install the app form store, there is no file in app's `LocalFolder`. You can check **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\{Package family name}\LocalState** to see if you have these images in your app's `LocalFolder`.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT yes images are present in localstate..

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT i added all visual assets in manifest file is that the problem..?

Comment: How you add the  visual assets in manifest file? And could you share the store link to your app?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT here i shared budlefile of my app https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242B617BA6BE2!9131&authkey=!ACQh_qcPrDBnbV8&ithint=folder%2cappxupload

Comment: I installed your app in my side. However, there is no image in "LocalState" folder. See [my capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDcLD.png). I think this is why tile images are not showing.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Sorry it's my mistake i changed the question see once..

Comment: i added images from ms-appx

Comment: I also used `ms-appx` for test. But I can't reproduce your problem. I tested both in debug and release mode and also installed from appxbundle. So could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT i am worked with my app, not with a sample..

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT is there any problem with adding all images in visual assets in manifest file..?

Comment: How you add the visual assets in manifest file? In Package.appxmanifest, we are setting visual assets for app's default tile. But your code is for SecondaryTile, I think they are not  relevant. The code you've posted can work in my side. So the problem here is not in the code. It may be related to the visual assets you used in the SecondaryTile. I'd suggest you create a simple example that only pin a  SecondaryTile and can reproduce your issue so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this below code, and last time i used 250x250 size image for both 150x150.jpg and 30x30.jpg, now i used exact size for images now the tile is working when app is in store..

```
Uri Squarelogo = new Uri(ms-appx:///TileImages/150x150.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Uri smalllogo = new Uri(ms-appx::///TileImages/30x30.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var tileActivationArguments = "MySecondaryTile Was Pinned At " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString();

SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(ShowId, title, tileActivationArguments, Squarelogo, TileSize.Square150x150);
secondaryTile.VisualElements.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Light;
secondaryTile.VisualElements.Wide310x150Logo = Squarelogo;
secondaryTile.VisualElements.Square30x30Logo = smalllogo;
secondaryTile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;
secondaryTile.VisualElements.ShowNameOnWide310x150Logo = true;

await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```